# Add number to existing number in textfield

Tags: swift

How do I assign the button to take the current number in a textfield and add plus one. The number in the textfield then generates into a barcode.

```
 @IBAction func generatePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if dataField.text?.isEmpty ?? true {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Get me outta here!", message:
            "Enter a ticket #", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: nil))

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("textField is empty")
    } else {
        if let text = dataField.text {

            let data = text.data(using: .ascii, allowLossyConversion: false)

            filter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator")
            filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 10, y: 10)
            let image = UIImage(ciImage: filter.outputImage!.transformed(by: transform))

            displayCodeView.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if my answer works for you. Feel free to ask me any questions :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your textField's text is a number or not instead of only check `isEmpty`

```
@IBAction func generatePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let number = Int(dataField.text ?? "") else {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Get me outta here!", message:
        "Enter a ticket #", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: nil))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("textField is empty")
        return
    }

    let data = "\(number + 1)".data(using: .ascii, allowLossyConversion: false)

    filter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator")
    filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 10, y: 10)
    let image = UIImage(ciImage: filter.outputImage!.transformed(by: transform))

    displayCodeView.image = image
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can easily achieve this:

```
@IBAction func generatePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    dataTextField.text = String(Int(dataTextField.text!)! + 1)
}
```

This is assuming you have a default value. Set a default value if you don't.

You could use `Double` for decimal values:

```
@IBAction func generatePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    dataTextField.text = String(Double(dataTextField.text!)! + 1)
}
```